# Displaying on text view in the image view

Tags: android

can someone please help me ? I am unable to display the result on the textview in the image view, could someone please help me to take a look. I want to display the result on the textview in image view. I tried to change many times and re-look it, however i am still not able to find anything that had gone wrong.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="sg.edu.rp.c346.lovecalculator.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/b_calculate"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/heart" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_female"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:hint="Female name" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_male"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et_female"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:hint="Male name" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b_calculate"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et_male"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Calculate" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_result"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="#ef3737"
    android:textSize="32dp" />
```

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText et_female, et_male;
Button b_calculate;
TextView tv_result;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    et_female = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_female);
    et_male = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_male);
    b_calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_calculate);
    tv_result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);

    b_calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (et_female.getText().toString().equals("")
                    && et_male.getText().toString().equals("")) {

                String female = et_female.getText().toString();
                String male = et_male.getText().toString();

                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                String day = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                String month = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.MONTH));
                String year = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.YEAR));

                String result_string = female + male + day + month + year;
                result_string = result_string.toLowerCase();
                result_string = result_string.trim();

                int seed = result_string.hashCode();

                Random r = new Random(seed);

                tv_result.setText((r.nextInt(100) + 1) + "%");

            }

        }
    });


}
```

}

Comment: where is ImageView in MainActivity

Comment: where did you add imageview in activity?

Comment: where you want to place image? top?

Comment: you are trying to display some number in a TextView not an ImageView.

Comment: Ohya, on the textview sorry guys!

Comment: left or right of textview?

Comment: The textview is inside the imageview, i want to print the text at it, however i can't print it out.

Comment: try using a framelayout and add textview as second child.In this way the texview would be displayed over imageview.

Answer (score 0):

You can set background of textview.

Try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_female"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:hint="Female name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_male"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et_female"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:hint="Male name" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b_calculate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et_male"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Calculate" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/b_calculate"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/heart"
        android:text="510"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#ef3737"
        android:textSize="32dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: However i am not able to set the text, it will not change when i pressed the button.

Answer (score 0):

Use a frame layout like so :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <ImageView 
      android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:scaleType="fitCenter"
      android:layout_height="250px"
      android:layout_width="250px"/>

   <TextView
      android:text="Frame Demo"
      android:textSize="30px"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Change sizes accordingly , the frame layout will automatically put the second child above the first child so the textview will be above the imageview and not hidden behind it.

Enjoy.